# Where to submit bug reports on Android EMM API?

Tags: android, google-api, bug-reporting, android-for-work

There is a problem with the service https://www.googleapis.com/androidenterprise/v1/enterprises/enterpriseId/products/productId/appRestrictionsSchema returning the wrong information in one of our apps. Where can we submit a bug report?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 1):

Google provides support for the Play EMM API via the [EMM Community forum](https://connect.googleforwork.com/community/developers/android/emm) only. You need to be registered to the [EMM Community](https://developers.google.com/android/work/register) to have access to this forum, but I guess you are already since it's a prerequisite for using this API.

Note that you can also retrieve the app restriction schema using the Android Management API by calling the method [applications.get](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.applications/get) and reading the field `managedProperties` in the response.

Comment: We are not an EMM provider so i don't think we can join that community. I found about the [devhub](https://enterprise.google.com/android/developers/applyDevHub/) in the Cloud Connect page. This seems to better relate to us. But then again i think now it makes more sense that our EMM supplier speaks with Google.